# FancyBox iFrame broke after Tables & Styles in IE

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, fancybox

I'm wondering if there's any particular rules regarding using and stylizing 'fancybox' windows. I've implemented a 'fancybox' using the iFrame call - and when I just had some simple text, a background color, and an Image; it rendered great IE 6+. BUT, now that I've added a simple table with some styles for buttons within - it breaks in 6/7.

Anything particular I should avoid implementing and putting inside an iFrame called .html while using fancybox supporting IE6/7?

**! Update** (please help me debug - here's what I have being called in the fancybox via iFrame):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style>

h1 { font-family: Georgia, Regular; font-size: 30px; color: #8E4925;  font-weight: 300;}
h2 { font-family: Georgia, Regular; font-size: 18px; color: #8E4925; line-height: 30px;  font-weight: 300; text-transform:Uppercase;}
p { font-family: Georgia, Regular; font-size: 16px; color: #000; padding: 4px; line-height: 25px;  font-weight: 300; }

</style>

</head>

<body style="background-color: #FFFDEF;">

<div id="wrap" style="width:650px;">

<div style="float:left; width: 300px;">



<table width="300" height="30">
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color: #CCCC99; height:40px; max-width:50px;"><center>TKTK</center></td>
    <td style="background-color: #CCCC99; height:40px; max-width:50px;"><center>TKTK</center></td>
    <td style="background-color: #CCCC99; height:40px; max-width:50px;"><center>TKTK</center></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color: #CCCC99; height:40px; max-width:50px;"><center>TKTK</center></td>
    <td style="background-color: #CCCC99; height:40px; max-width:50px;"><center>TKTK</center></td>
    <td style="background-color: #CCCC99; height:40px; max-width:50px;"><center>TKTK</center></td>
  </tr>
</table>


<table width="300" height="30" >
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color: #CCCC99; height:40px; max-width:50px;"><center>TKTK</center></td>
    <td style="background-color: #CCCC99; height:40px; max-width:50px;"><center>TKTK</center></td>
    <td style="background-color: #CCCC99; height:40px; max-width:50px;"><center>TKTK</center></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color: #CCCC99; height:40px; max-width:50px;"><center>TKTK</center></td>
    <td style="background-color: #CCCC99; height:40px; max-width:50px;"><center>TKTK</center></td>
  </tr>
</table>


<br />


<table width="300" height="30">
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color: #CCCC99; height:40px; max-width:50px;"><center>TKTK</center></td>
    <td style="background-color: #CCCC99; height:40px; max-width:50px;"><center>TKTK</center></td>
    <td style="background-color: #CCCC99; height:40px; max-width:50px;"><center>TKTK</center></td>
  </tr>
</table>



</div>

<div style="float:right; width: 300px">

<img src="http://rh-dev.us.mytest.com/crown/features/AmericanGrown/imgs/Cover.jpg" style="border:0px; margin-top:40px;"/>


</div>
</div>

       <!-- SiteCatalyst Code version: H.17.
Copyright 1997-2008 Omniture, Inc. More info available at
http://www.omniture.com -->
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mytest.com/js/s_code.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"><!--
/************* DO NOT ALTER ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE ! **************/
var s_code=s.t();if(s_code)document.write(s_code)//--></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"><!--
if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf('MSIE')>=0)document.write(unescape('%3C')+'\!-'+'-')
//--></script><noscript><a href="http://www.omniture.com" title="Web Analytics"><img
src="http://code.mytest.com/b/ss/ranhrollup/1/H.17--NS/0"
height="1" width="1"style="border:3px solid #FFFDEF; alt="" /></a></noscript><!--/DO NOT REMOVE/-->
<!-- End SiteCatalyst code version: H.17. -->



</body>
</html>
```

**FancyBox JS inline:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.ui.all.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://rh-dev.us.mytest.com/crown/features/AmericanGrown/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://rh-dev.us.mytest.com/crown/features/AmericanGrown/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js">
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://rh-dev.us.mytest.com/crown/features/AmericanGrown/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen">

<!--JS for Fancybox iFrame buybtn-->

<script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                        /*
                        *   Examples - various
                        */
                          $("#various7").fancybox({
                                'width'                         : 700,
                                'height'                        : 500,
                                'autoScale'                     : false,
                                'transitionIn'          : 'elastic',
                                'transitionOut'         : 'fade',
                                'enableEscapeButton'    : 'true',
                                'type'                  : 'iframe',
                                'speedIn'               : 250,
                                'speedOut'              : 500,


                        });

                });
</script>

<!--End JS for Fancybox iFrame buybtn-->
```

**CTA:**

```
<a id="various7" href="http://rh-dev.us.mytest.com/crown/features/AmericanGrown/iframe/buybutton.html" name="various7"><img src="http://rh-dev.us.randomhouse.com/crown/features/AmericanGrown/imgs/buythebook_btn.png" border="0"></a>
```

Comment: What exactly is breaking? Is the content still loading but not displaying properly? Or is nothing loading at all? I am on a Mac so I don't have IE to actually look at, but I might be able to help.

Comment: Thanks for the response! It's actually just not 'fanyboxing' in IE. It just links to the .html page (I'm using iFrame fancybox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the last trialing comma after the last API option

```
'speedOut': 500, //<-- remove this comma
```

that crates the issue with IE

Comment: Are you serious? Wow, thanks man - I'll plug in it first thing in the morning at work!

Comment: Should I try removing the comma after each; width and height?

Comment: nope, the comma is to separate the options of each other. If you set the last comma, then IE is expecting another option (and generating a js error afterwards)... so remove only the last one